# knockoutjs overriding bindinghandlers

Tags: knockout.js

Hi I'm trying to set ko up so that on any click handler being called a little bit of custom code is run.
Whats the easiest way to add some pre and post code to the 'click' bindings handler?

Answer (score 17):

You can either create a custom binding that wraps the `click` binding or save off references to the original `init` and `update` functions of the `click` binding and replace the real one.

You could either choose to execute some code in the `update` function which will be triggered when the model value is updated (either by the event handler attached in the init function or programmatically) or execute your code as part of the actual handler.  It sounds to me like you want the latter.

Your binding might look like:

```
(function() {
    var originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init,
        originalUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.click.update;

    ko.bindingHandlers.click = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
            var wrappedValueAccessor = function() {
                return function(data, event) {
                   //run some pre code
                   ko.bindingHandlers.click.preOnClick.call(viewModel, data, event);

                   valueAccessor().call(viewModel, data, event);

                   //run some post code
                   ko.bindingHandlers.click.postOnClick.call(viewModel, data, event);
                };

            };

            originalInit(element, wrappedValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        },
        update: originalUpdate,
        preOnClick: function(data, event) {
            alert("pre code for " + data.id);
        },
        postOnClick: function(data, event) {
            alert("post code for " + data.id);
        }
    };
})();
```

I split out the pre/post code such that at run-time you could override `ko.bindingHandlers.click.preOnClick` or `ko.bindingHandlers.click.postOnClick`

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PksAn/

If you need to run custom code in the update function, then you can split it out and run your pre and post code there and execute `originalUpdate` in between.

Comment: RP, can u please check this? I need a custom binding provider,    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535102/binding-jagged-array-with-knockout

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the code is correct and the solution is proper.

Comment: @user960567 - my suggestion would have been to use `$data.myProp` when possible. Otherwise, a binding provider that is more tolerant could be like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ruaLJ/

Comment: Thanks. But is there is any issue regarding your binding provider. Because when I view the source of knockout, it seems the error is coming from parsing JSON by the native java-script code instead of knockout. Is there is any disadvantages or data loose/corruption chance in using this binding provider?

Comment: It depends. If you have something like a `with` or `foreach` binding  that fails to parse, then it will try to bind the children as though it wasn't there.  Additionally, if the undefined value suddenly is populated it won't do anything to "re-bind" the element.

Comment: For newer versions of Knockout, you need to also pass the `bindingContext`: http://jsfiddle.net/PksAn/63/

Comment: How do you override the "attr" binding? I get "originalInit is not a function"