# Knockout - Assign a CSS class to an input from the view model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a view model that has the observable "yearsOld" which is bound to an html input.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:yearsOld">

    var viewModel = {
      yearsOld: ko.observable("");
    }
```

Is there any way to add a css class to the input from the viewModel?  The reason I'm asking is because I need to add a css class named "positive-integer" to the input bound to yearsOld so that my 3rd party jQuery library will restrict non-numeric input on that bound input field.

Note:  I'm aware of the [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) that knockout provides to place on a input field, but that doesn't help me here since the css is not necessarily dynamic.  I'm just hoping to be able to put a css class on the input from the viewModel instead of putting it directly on each individual input.  Even if this doesn't make sense to *you*, I'm just curious if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly is possible, and you'd do it via the css binding. I don't understand why you think the css binding won't work for you.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
<input data-bind="value: yearsOld, css: { 'positive-integer': positiveIntegersOnly }" />

var viewModel = {
   yearsOld: ko.observable(),
   positiveIntegersOnly: ko.observable(false)
}
```

To apply the 'positive-integer' class:

```
viewModel.positiveIntegersOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first my answer was no, this is not possible. But after some research I have discovered that it is entirely possible.

Using the wonderful answer from this question here: [knockoutjs overriding bindinghandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002163/knockoutjs-overriding-bindinghandlers) you are able to  override the behaviour of the value binding, and add the desired behaviour necessary.

```
var originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init,
    originalUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.value.update;

ko.bindingHandlers.value= {
    init: originalInit,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        // only apply to inputs, and if value is a number and is greater than 0
        if ($element.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "input" && !isNaN(value) && value > 0) {
            $element.addClass('positive-integer');
        }
        else {
            // otherwise ensure the class is removed
            $element.removeClass('positive-integer');
        }
        // call the original update function
        originalUpdate(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};
```

This code will run before the regular `value:` binding code, and update your elements class (jQuery is needed, but only because I am lazy - should be easily converted if necessary).

Full working JS fiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/sp3uF/

Answer (score 0):

You want the next scenario: user enters some non-numeric and your input changes the style?

Two ways: jQuery and css binding:

```
//jQuery
var viewModel = {
    hasNonNumeric: function(){//not implemented},
    yearsOld: ko.observable(),
    yearsOld.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (this.hasNonNumeric(newValue)) {
            $('input').addClass("positive-integer");
        }
        else {
            $('input').removeClass("positive-integer");
        }
    });
}​

//knockout
var viewModel = {
        hasNonNumeric: function() { //not implemented},
        yearsOld: ko.observable(),
        scareUser: ko.computed(function() {
            var result = false;
            if (this.hasNonNumeric(this.yearsOld())) {
                result = true;
            }            
            return result;
        });
    }​

<input data-bind="value: yearsOld, css: { 'positive-integer': scareUser}" />
```

Comment: Doing `$('input').addClass("positive-integer");` would change ALL input elements on the page to have/not have this class whenever you edit `yearsOld` to satisfy `hasNonNUmeric()`

Comment: I used it just for example. You can use any selector you need: $('#theinput').

Comment: Ok! Just thought it was worth pointing out so someone doesn't fall into that trap