# Binding Jagged Array with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jagged-arrays

I have having problem to binding jagged array in knockout-js. I have search a lot but could not found any thing. Let make a simple example,

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
<div  data-bind="style: { textAlign: align, backgroundColor:  bgColor, fontFamily: fontFamily, fontSize: size, color: color }, text: title"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the my array,

```
var items = [{
                    title: 'A',
                    align: 'right',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica',
                    color: '#777777',
                    bgColor: '#ffffff'
            }, 
            {
                    title: 'A',
                    align: 'right',
                    size: 'large',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica'
            }
            {
                    size: 'large',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica',
                    color: '#777777'
            }]
```

Clearly sometime some property(ies) are missing? So I get *** is not defined* error. How to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options.  You can make sure your ViewModels aren't jagged.  This is accomplished well by using the knockout mapping plugin against your model and having it use a constructor of your type.  this way you can even define defaults

the other option is to reference the values off of the $data context.  IE:

```
<div  data-bind="style: { textAlign: $data.align, backgroundColor:  $data.bgColor, fontFamily: $data.fontFamily, fontSize: $data.size, color: $data.color }, text: $data.title"></div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drdamour/Xp9Er/

Comment: Is there is a no way to tell the knockout to ignore these properties.

Comment: not with the default binding provider, the $data syntax is really useful for "might not be there" scenarios.  I've used a custom binding called init before that will create the observable if it isn't there.  You really should look at knockout mapping plugin for converting your model to a view model.  it's more work but really helps long term.