# KnockoutJS - how do I debounce clicks?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, debouncing

I want to change what happens by default when a button is pressed - I need to prevent buttons from being double-clicked.

One option is wrapping the functions the buttons are bound to in _.once() or _.throttle() from underscore, but it would be better if this were handled higher up the stack.

So I found this question: [knockoutjs overriding bindinghandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002163/knockoutjs-overriding-bindinghandlers) and the fiddle referenced in the answer (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PksAn/) and tried to do something with it. Below is the original code from the fiddle.

```
(function(){
var originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init,
    originalUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.click.update;

ko.bindingHandlers.click = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var wrappedValueAccessor = function() {
            return function(data, event) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.click.preOnClick.call(viewModel, data, event);
                valueAccessor().call(viewModel, data, event);
                ko.bindingHandlers.click.postOnClick.call(viewModel, data, event);
            };
        };

        originalInit(element, wrappedValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    },
    update: originalUpdate,
    preOnClick: function(data, event) {
    },
    postOnClick: function(data, event) {
    }
};
})();
```

I tried to wrap wrappedValueAccessor with _.throttle() and I also tried wrapping the nested function but it turns out that valueAccessor() is returning a new function each time and I think that this is what I'm supposed to wrap.

That code is here: (from knockout-2.2.1.debug.js starting at line 2043)

```
function makeValueAccessor(bindingKey) {
    return function () { return parsedBindings[bindingKey] }
}
```

Which means I'd have to get into the internals of knockout which seems wrong.

So my question is, am I on to the right idea here or is the approach completely wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a `debounce` version of your `valueAccessor` returned handler function and store it, and return that debounced version from the `wrappedValueAccessor` function:

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var debouncedAccessor = _.debounce(valueAccessor(), 800, true)
    var wrappedValueAccessor = function() {
        return debouncedAccessor;
    };        
    originalInit(element, wrappedValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
},
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/uvnDc/).

Comment: This works beautifully, unless the click handler is not a method on the current binding context object. For instance, if you use `click: $root.clickHandlerMethod` or `click: childObject.clickHandlerMethod`, the this pointer is still the bound context object, NOT `$root` or `childObject`, which is what I think the user would expect.

Comment: init function has another parameter bindingContext, which must be passed.
'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) { }
(https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html )